# use hypersetup in own package

Tags: hyperref, packages

I'm trying to create my own style file (`.sty`-file) where more or less the whole preamble is defined. The reason behind is, that users of my stylefile just have to use my package and don't have to care about styling.

In my stylefile I create some new commmands like the following:

```
\newcommand{\theversion}{Version 1.0}
\newcommand{\thedocumenttitle}{My Basic Title}
\newcommand{\theauthor}{John Doe}
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}
```

Users of my stylefile can now "override" these settings with `renewcommand` in their actual main file like so:

```
\renewcommand{\theversion}{Version 2.0}
\renewcommand{\thedocumenttitle}{My Overwritten Title}
```

Now my problem is the following: I use the `hyperref` package in the stylefile and also use the `hypersetup` command:

```
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={\thedocumenttitle{} - \theversion{}},
pdfauthor={\theauthor{}},
linkcolor={black},
urlcolor={black},
citecolor={black}}
```

Although I renew the commands in the main file, the old values are used in the `hypersetup` because the `hypersetup` is defined in the style and not in the main file. The renewing happens in the main file and therefore *after* the `hypersetup` command i guess.

So my questions are:

1. In general: Is it a good aproach to define commands in the stylefile and let the users of the stylefile renew these commands if needed?
2. How can I solve my `hypersetup` issue? Sure, I could put the `hypersetup` in the main file after the `renewcommand`s. But I don't want the users of the stylefile care about such things. Is there any different (better) approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can delay the execution of `\hypersetup` for the information entries. However, it must be set *before* `hyperref` uses it. Usually this time is `\begin{document}`, that means, `\AtBeginDocument` can be used *before* `hyperref` is loaded:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={\thedocumenttitle\space - \theversion},%
    pdfauthor={\theauthor},%
  }%
}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

**Remarks:**

- Do not use empty braces inside the entries (`\theauthor{}`). Macro `\theauthor` does not have an argument and the braces will remain in the entry.

Comment: The drawback of this method is that if the end user wants its linkcolor to be red and inserts `\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}` in its preamble, the `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{...,linkcolor=black,...}}` from the `.sty` file will overwrite his setup. Hence the end user has to be told to specify its own `\hypersetup` choices not in the preamble but in the document's body. I asked a specific question on this subject: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191887/18401.