# Is it possible to collect hyperref's \hypersetup argument?

Tags: hyperref, package-writing, documentclass-writing, preamble

Suppose you want to set, in a `.sty` or `.cls` file, some `hyperref`'s options in case the end user loads this package. Because that's only at the begin of the document you know if `hyperref` has been loaded, you have to use something like:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \hypersetup{%
      ⟨my advised hyperref's options⟩%
    }%
  }{%
  }%
}%
```

This has already been discussed in [use hypersetup in own package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124778/use-hypersetup-in-own-package).

But a drawback of this method is that if the end user has different tastes and inserts `\hypersetup{⟨another hyperref's options⟩}` in its preamble, the `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{...}}` from the `.sty` or `.cls` file will overwrite his setup.

In order to circumvent this problem, the end user may specify its own `\hypersetup` choices not in the preamble but in the document's body. But suppose you'd like to not distract the end users with such complication, would it be possible to collect hyperref's `\hypersetup` argument?

The idea is to get, at the begin of the document, the possible options that have been specified either at the `\usepackage` level (this is easy with `\@ifpackagewith` macro) or as `\hypersetup` argument, and not overwrite them.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I've found, not a real answer to the main question, but a solution to the underlying problem (namely how not override end user `hyperref`'s options with an `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{...}}` declaration in a `.sty` or `.cls` file): instead of

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \hypersetup{%
      ⟨my advised hyperref's options⟩%
    }%
  }{%
  }%
}%
```

it should be enough to use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  ⟨my advised hyperref's options⟩
}{hyperref}%
```

These options would be taken in account if (and only if) `hyperref` is loaded and only at its loading time. Hence `⟨another hyperref's options⟩` specified either with

```
\hypersetup{⟨another hyperref's options⟩}
```

or with

```
\usepackage[⟨another hyperref's options⟩]{hyperref}
```

will override `⟨my advised hyperref's options⟩` specified in the `.sty` or `.cls` file.