# Changing citation colour in included TikZ standalone file only

Tags: hyperref, standalone

**Problem:** I am currently writing a document that includes a flow diagram in an appendix. In the flow diagram, I would like to be able to include citations within the `TikZ` nodes (it is quite technical and requires pointing to different software/methods etc.). I wanted to change the colours of the citation numbers within the `\includestandalone` `TikZ` diagram but cannot see a way to change the colours local using `\hypersetup` of the `hyperref` package. When I compile the `standalone` file of the MWE individually I get (the background looks black on my system for some reason, it is white on the preview):

[image: Standalone link]

I came across this answer by Heiko Oberdiek to the question [use hypersetup in own package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124780/273733) and it seems that `\hypersetup` needs to be set *before* `hyperref` uses it. How can I have a change in the citation colour within a `TikZ` `standalone` file that only applies to that diagram?

**MWE**:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{stand_alone.tex}

\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibb.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [anchor=west] (Test) at (0, 0) {\cite{a1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\end{filecontents}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibb.bib}
@article{a1,author = {Author, One and Lorem, Ipsum},title={Random title}}
\end{filecontents}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{bibb.bib}

\begin{document}
This citation should have no colour: \cite{a1}
\bigskip

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includestandalone{stand_alone}
\caption{The citation number in this figure should be blue}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\bigskip
This citation should also have no colour: \cite{a1}

\end{document}
```

**How it currently looks:**

[image: How it currently looks]

I am compiling with:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
```

I am new to both `standalone` and `TikZ` and I searched TeX.SE but this exceeds my knowledge of both of those packages/classes and I am not sure if I even know the correct terms to search, sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself editing the `biblatex` style I am using (`numeric-comp`) with:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
    {\color{blue}\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}%
}
```

The `\cite` definitions for each style can be found from the `biblatex` style files. The output now:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{stand_alone.tex}

\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibb.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [anchor=west] (Test) at (0, 0) {\cite{a1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\end{filecontents}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibb.bib}
@article{a1,author = {Author, One and Lorem, Ipsum},title={Random title}}
\end{filecontents}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}       % --- Added
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
    {\color{blue}\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}%
}

\addbibresource{bibb.bib}

\begin{document}
This citation should have no colour: \cite{a1}
\bigskip

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includestandalone{stand_alone}
\caption{The citation number in this figure should be blue}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\bigskip
This citation should also have no colour: \cite{a1}

\end{document}
```

Not sure if this is the best solution or whether a solution within `standalone` or `hyperref` would be best but this works.